# Can you pin the model version of Google Speech to Text?

Tags: python, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I would like to transcribe audio using the Google speech to text API (STT), but I need the transcriptions to be consistent over time. In other words, even if Google improves the STT model, is it possible to pin the version of the STT model I used originally so the transcriptions stay consistent? I'm using the Google speech Python client library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to define a specific version of the STT model. What I could suggest to be somewhat consistent is to define the `model` to be used on your STT [RecognitionConfig()](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/speech_v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.RecognitionConfig).

> model
>
> Which model to select for the given request. Select the model
> best suited to your domain to get best results. If a model is not
> explicitly specified, then we auto-select a model based on the
> parameters in the RecognitionConfig.
>
> Model | Description
>
> - **command_and_search** |    Best for short queries such as
>   voice commands or voice search.
> - **phone_call** | Best for audio that
>   originated from a phone call (typically recorded at an 8khz sampling
>   rate).
> - **video** | Best for audio that originated from video or includes
>   multiple speakers. Ideally the audio is recorded at a 16khz or greater
>   sampling rate. This is a premium model that costs more than the
>   standard rate.
> - **default** |   Best for audio that is not one of the specific
>   audio models. For example, long-form audio. Ideally the audio is
>   high-fidelity, recorded at a 16khz or greater sampling rate.